# how to enable the throttling mechanism in WSO2 EI 6.5.0 product?

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am trying to enable the throttling mechanism in the WSO2 EI 6.5.0 product (because the throttling option is disabled by default), but I cannot find out the wso2throttle.mar file or the wso2throttle project or any information how to build it. Coud you please give me some advice on this subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use the throttle mediator https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Throttle+Mediator and enable throttling per service or API.

Comment: Great, Thank you very much for your answer! It's extremely useful.